# How do I write this piece of node js code asynchronously

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to handle a post request. I want this to get a post requst, run a query and grab some data and then modify a few variables. Then render the index.ejs file along with the changed variables.

It's working fine. But the problem here is, it is rendering the page first and updating the variables after that.
How do I proceed in the opposite order ? I guess maybe, I should change my code asynchronously. I don't know how to do that.

```
 app.post('/id',function (req, res) {

    // Run a mysql query

 con.query('SELECT * FROM new_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9', 
 function(error,results, fields) {
        if (error)
            throw error;

       //update some variables here

    });

// render the index.ejs file and an updated varible (ejs and express stuff) 

 res.render("index",{
changed_variable:changed_variable
   });

});
```

Comment: Did you try to put `res.render` inside your query success callback?

Comment: I also suggest you to have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/async

Comment: Thanks a tonne, man. I tried a lot of stuff, but was too dumb to not try this one. Putting res.render within the query success callback worked !

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put your `res.render` inside you query success callback like below:

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM new_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9', function(error,results, fields) {
  if (error)
    throw error;

    //update some variables here
    res.render("index",{ changed_variable:changed_variable });
})
```

However the suggested approach would be to use `async` module, install it as follow:

`npm install --save async`

With `async` module you can write something like this.

```
router.get('/id', function(req, res) {
  async.series([
    con.query('SELECT * FROM new_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9', function(error,results, fields) {
        if (error)
            throw error;

       //update some variables here

    })
  ],
  function(err, results) {
    res.render("index",{ changed_variable:changed_variable });
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is already asynchronous. If you want to render the page after the query has finished processing you should place the render inside the callback.

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM new_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9', 
function(error,results, fields) {
    if (error)
        throw error;

    //update some variables here
    res.render("index",{
      changed_variable:changed_variable
    });

})
```